# Adding markers to map from ArrayList

Tags: android, google-maps, arraylist, google-maps-api-3

I have the coordinates of my markers in a LatLng arraylist. I add all the markers to a marker arraylist.

```
for(int i=0; i<markers_location.length; i++){
    coords_markers.add(new LatLng(lat_markers.get(i), lon_markers.get(i)));}

List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<markers_location.length; i++){
    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coords_markers.get(i)));
    markers.add(marker);
}
```

How can I then add these markers to the map? I tried this:

```
mMap.addMarker(markers.get(0));
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: you have already added the marker when you called mMap.addMarker in your for loop.

Comment: You are right, I already added it at the for loop. I was just confused because I needed the marker arraylist to change all the markericons on zoom change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(int i=0; i<markers_location.length; i++){
coords_markers.add(new LatLng(
lat_markers.get(i).getLatitude, 
lon_markers.get(i).getLongitude));}
```